# AngularJS share model between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing an application to show some charts and some controls to filter the data presented. The structure of the HTML page is the same, so I though I could make an HTML template and use it with different controllers, one for each chart type and one for each set of controls to filter a specific chart data.
My idea was to have a default HTML that I fill with a chart controller and a filter controller accordingly to the type requested.

To achieve this idea, I'm currently using, and abusing of, prototypical inheritance. I have a ChartController that defines two scope models that will hold the chart and the filter controls configuration. Then I have two child controllers, for exemple, LineChartController and LineChartFiltersController, that populate those two variables with the configuration specific for the chart type.

Everything works fine, but I don't like this approach because my child controllers stay very dependent on the parent, and it's difficult to test and even to understand from where the $scope models come for someone that is not aware of how the controllers were designed.

As requested, here are some snippets:

```
app.controller('ChartController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.chart = {};
  $scope.filters = {};
}]);
app.controller('LineChartController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.chart.tooltip = {...};
  $scope.chart.commonSeriesSettings = {...};
}]);
app.controller('LineChartFiltersController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.filters.beginDate = ...;
  $scope.filters.endDate = ...;
  $scope.filters.granularity = ...;
}]);
```

Then I have a route that redirects to the HTML template common to all charts and uses the ChartController.
Inside of it I include the LineChartController and the LineChartFiltersController creating the relation parent/children:

```
<!-- main template -->
<div ng-include="/partials/line_chart.html"></div>
...
<div ng-include="/partials/line_chart_filters.html"></div>
```

line_chart.html

```
<div ng-controller="LineChartController">
  <div chart="widget"></div>
</div>
```

line_chart_filters.html

```
<div ng-controller="LineChartFiltersController">
  <!-- date pickets, sliders, etc. that use $scope.filter -->
</div>
```

I know that (perhaps) the best approach to share data between controllers is injecting a service. But I want to share model data, the charts configuration and the filter controls, and not some business models that are fetched from a server. It's hard for me to see the advantage of the services in this situation, because with the service I get a singleton object. Coming from typical OOP programming, I was expecting to get an instance that would be specific to the controllers instantiated. As far as I know, the singleton service is the same across different controllers. For this reason, I used scope inheritance.

Is there another approach to achieve my goal? Or injecting a service would be more suitable?

Comment: I much prefer code instead of long paragraphs...

Comment: Can the linechart and linefilters e ach be a service containing the appropriate configuration data?  Or, if they encapsulate DOM elements, you should consider directives.

Comment: They don't encapsulate DOM elements, and the charts are already rendered throughout a directive. So I believe directives aren't the solution. With services would work, but I get singleton objects right? It seems kind of weird to save model data/state in a singleton object. If the controller changes, I would have to reset that service (erasing all the models/current state). Besides, with a service I would have to coordinate its state between the controllers who use it if I am restoring the page (ex: when the user shares the URL and one controller uses data that its filled by the other).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something similar done in three different ways. I don't follow your use case so I am unsure which may work well for you.

Here are the three ways I know of to accomplish something similar.

1. Use a [Custom Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to get the information and display it in the same way. If the listing is different between the pages this may not make sense.
2. Create a [Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) which incapsulates the logic and state for the information which needs to be used across controllers. This works well if the important factor is the logic and state of the information and the display may be different.
3. Use Observers to communicate information between controllers. I find this to be a frustrating route because it is **hard** to test. It does work well when there is an even which occurs often and needs to trigger multiple actions, but I do not recommend this route.

Posting some code with your question may help. Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe a custom directive would be a good fit for this situation. That chart library I'm using displays the charts through directives already. I just have to pass the configuration. And it's this configuration that I'm sharing between controllers through scope inheritance / prototypical inheritance. With services, I get singleton objects. It just not seems right because I was expecting to get an instance for each chart type. Using observers/watchers seems like a bit extreme for this case.